# Why are maven selenium projects on Jenkins running 2 parallel projects at the same time?

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins

Here is my problem: I have created a project to "Trigger/call builds on other projects". This project will be like a test-suite to kick off my other selenium  projects (Which is one maven project with tests and framework) to run on Jenkins.

[image: Maven Project]

When I run this test suite then it runs 2 projects at the same time and the others are queued. I want 1 project to run at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this through: Go to --> Manage Jenkins --> Configure System --> Change "# of executors" to 1 under the "Maven Project Configuration". Now it will run 1 project at a time.

[image]